# TypeError: Image data cannot be converted to float // When importing .png images

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, png, typeerror

I saved inverted binarized images after extracting lines from tables as png (did it with opencv). Now when I try to load them with opencv or matplotlib it will show NoneType or the error in the headline. I have checked many different posts with the same error. I guess it has something to do with the image data.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


imgs = cv2.imread('Users/marius/Desktop/PDF/imgvh/1.png')
cv2.imshow('Users/marius/Desktop/PDF/imgvh/1.png', imgs)
```

[image]

The error which occurs when using cv2:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'
```

Using matplotlib in this way:

```
imgs = plt.imshow('Users/marius/Desktop/PDF/imgvh/1.png')
plt.show()
```

leads to the following error:

```
TypeError: Image data of dtype <U49 cannot be converted to float
```

Comment: I think the Stack Overflow server has changed your shared file. Can you share it via another method as well please? Dropbox? Google Drive?

Comment: @Mark Setchell I did just upload it again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **OpenCV** part doesn't work because you omitted the slash at the start of the path ahead of `Users/marius...`. It should be:

```
imgs = cv2.imread('/Users/marius/Desktop/PDF/imgvh/1.png')
```

---

The **matplotlib** part doesn't work because it should be:

```
imgs = cv2.imread('/Users/marius...')

plt.imshow(imgs)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see that. I searched for hours. Thanks a lot. Sometimes you can't see the wood for the trees...